# RGBA transparency not outputting as clear when overlaid onto image

Tags: python, opencv, rgba

I have got a script to spot a pothole in an image and draw an ellipse around it. I have two images. one the original image and then a separate numpy array which is white with a red ellipse on it. I have converted the ellipse image RGBA image with the intention of overlaying it onto the original image, using the code below. However the output image ( new_img ) is showing a blend with the ellipse image background still showing at half opacity (because the transparency is set in blend() however I would like the white background to be completely clear and the ellipse to be half transparent) . In other words the for loop is not creating a RGBA image with alpha of 0. Attached are the input, ellipse image and output.

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2

# Make True pixels red
RGB[test_ellipse==255]  = [255,0,0]
# Make False pixels blue
RGB[test_ellipse==1] = [255,255,255]

image = cv2.imread(file_path , cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
test = Image.fromarray(RGB)
over = test.convert('RGBA')
datas = over.getdata()


newData = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
       newData.append(item)

over.putdata(newData)
background = Image.fromarray(image)
background = background.convert('RGBA')
new_img = Image.blend(background, over, 0.5)
new_img.show()
```

[image: Input] [image: ellipse overlay] [image: Current output]

Comment: You don't need any loops, nor any lists, nor any PIL nor any blending. Just create a single layer with `np.zeros_like(MAINIMAGE)` and draw your ellipse in it. This will be your alpha channel. Stack it with your main image using `greyPlusAlpha = np.dstack((MAINIMAGE, alpha))`.

Comment: The ellipse is drawn by a previous script automatically so I need it to be able to take the output from that directly and overlay it. Hence I take that numpy array and try and turn it into something that can be overlaid.

Comment: Try using GIMP or Photoshop or Paint to make a mid-grey image the same size as your pothole image. Paint in a fully white circle and a separate fully black circle and save as PNG. Open as greyscale in OpenCV and do the `np.dstack()` I suggested and save the result. View the saved result.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will give you an idea of adding an alpha channel. I just mocked up a dummy alpha channel with a painting program, making it mid-grey with one black and one white circle:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image and alpha
im    = cv2.imread('pothole.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
alpha = cv2.imread('alpha.png',   cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Make grey pothole picture 3 channel grey and add alpha layer
res = np.dstack((im,im,im,alpha))
cv2.imwrite('result.png', res)
```

[image]

You can maybe see the effect more clearly if I undertile with a chessboard like Photoshop does:

[image]

Comment: when i use your method, so i change Image.blend(background, over, 0.5) in my code to np.dstack((background,background,background,over)) I still get the same result. as in the white in the over image is only semi transparent

Comment: Please try running exactly the code in my answer with the image in my answer and see if that works on your machine. Thank you.

Comment: when I run exactly your code with the two images, I get the error:   TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'     for the last line

Comment: Mmm, can you print `im.shape` and `alpha.shape` please?

Comment: error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Ok, so it didn't load at all, so you probably have a little error in the path/filename. Check you have spelled the filename correctly and try running `os.system('pwd')` to check that the directory your program is running in is the same as the one where the images are.

Comment: ive changed it so the file names give the full file path and file name.  now the error is in the dstack line: line 9, in <module>
    res = np.dstack((im,im,im,alpha))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dstack

Comment: What are the shapes now that I mentioned earlier?

Comment: both are (563, 749)

Comment: I have got it working and get the same result as you